# Where are the "Admitted Aircraft symbols" on Jeppesen VFR aerodrome charts defined?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

Jeppesen VFR aerodrome charts depict several symbols for "admitted aircraft". However, even after checking several symbol legends I never found a definition of these symbols. Does anyone know where these are defined?

[image: admitted aircraft on jeppesen vfr aerodrome chart]

Comment: Are you asking what the term "admitted aircraft" means, or what each of the various specific aircraft symbols mean, or both?

Comment: @quietflyer I'm looking for a definition of the symbols, meaning which aircraft are admitted. The third one seems to be a glider and the last one obviously a helicopter, but what do the other symbols mean?

Comment: 4th is probably ultralight, but what on earth is difference between 1st and 2nd?

Comment: Tricycle gear vs. taildragger maybe?

Comment: @quietflyer The first symbol admits aircraft that have lost their propeller and are now gliders.  The second admits those that still have their propeller.

Comment: 1,3,4 & 5 are pretty obvious. 2 is the baffling one IMO

Comment: Really, the 2nd is evocative of a warbird, but that wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I was actually thinking warbird for 2 but am trying to find a definitive answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the help of Bianfable's answer I took it upon myself to email Jeppesen to get the correct answer.

---

[image: Jeppesen Email]
[image: Jeppesen Attachment 1]
[image: Jeppesen Attachment 3]

Comment: Excellent, thanks for going the extra mile.

Answer (score 4):

These symbols are part of the **[Jeppesen VFR Manual](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/personal-solutions/aviation/bottlang-airfield-manual.jsp)** (formerly called *Bottlang Airfield Manual*). The Jeppeson website contains a [sample](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/general/schoenhagen-web-2008.pdf) for one airfield:

> [image: Jeppesen VFR Manual sample]
>
> **(3)** Aircraft admitted at the Aerodrome / Am Flugplatz zugelassene
> Luftfahrzeuge

Unfortunately, the sample does not explain what each of the aircraft symbols mean. A [briefing bulletin](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/pdfs/briefingbulletinNov2015.pdf) announced some change in the design of these charts, but also does not explain the symbols:

> [image: Jeppesen VFR Manual design change]

Unlike the [IFR charts legend](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf), Jeppesen does not publish a legend for the VFR Manual online. So it looks like you have to purchase the full VFR Manual (either from Jeppesen or other dealers, price is [over 100 euros](https://www.siebert.aero/Katalog/Karten-Medien/Karten-und-Handbcher/Jeppesen-VFR-Manual)).

If you search on Google, you will find some (probably illegal) uploads of VFR Manuals on several dubious websites. I'm not going to download any of those, but if you really want to know, you might find an answer there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would’ve accepted it and given you the bounty if nobody would’ve posted the definition. However, as wbeard52 even contacted their support and has posted a definition, I accepted his answer.

Comment: @rauberdaniel I fully agree. Especially considering my answer says you have to spend hundreds of euros and wbeard52 got it for free, I think he deserves the bounty :)